# Change RCSKEYWORD in CVS

Tags: version-control, md5, keyword, cvs, rcs

I have a problem with CVS KEYWORD. 
Let me explain: 
In my source files (*.c) I have in the header a keyword "$Id" and this after checkout return a string:

> read.adb,v 1.1.1.2 2005/02/20 17:57:20 dprice Exp

But my team and another team, use a different version of CVS for the same project. 
When they make a checkout of the software, the $Id keyword expression return:

> read.adb,v 1.1.1.2 2005-02-20 17:57:20 dprice Exp

the string is different for the format of data separation: from "/" to "-". 
This is a very big problem when I generate a md5. This md5 will be different for each team.

How I can change the string of $Id ?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the cvs source code? http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/cvs/ccvs/src/

Comment: I see "sanity.sh" in the src directory. In this file appear `RCSKEYDATE="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]"`. But I don't have any idea about how I can use this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modify rcs.c source code:

```
sprintf (buf, "%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", year, mon, mday, hour, min, sec);
```

but I don't understand why I had a different result with the same version of cvs.

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=479752

Looks like the default date format changed in version 1.12.x. As per that bug report, you can add `DateFormat=old` to `$CVSROOT/CVSROOT/config`

Comment: I try this option!